# Why can't I use format specifier on DataGrid Value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tostring

```
string Foo = selectedrow.Cells["Foo"].Value.ToString("D5");
```

Gives me error of

```
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

so I had to use

```
string Foo = selectedrow.Cells["Foo"].Value.ToString().PadLeft(5,'0');
```

Anyone who can explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataGridViewCell.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) is of type `System.Object`. The [`Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method does not take any arguments. Therefore, you cannot provide a format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the DataType in advance, you need to cast the Value first, to be able to then use the ToString method you're looking for:

```
string dateTime = ((DateTime)(selectedrow.Cells["Today"].Value)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string number = ((decimal)(selectedrow.Cells["Price"].Value)).ToString("N2");
```